# Integral matrix for $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was playing around with the idea of derivative/integral matrices in the following example:

Given V $\subseteq$ $\mathbb R_{n}[x]$ with basis $\mathscr B=\{x^a, a\in [0,n]\}$ and representative matrix $\mathbb 1_n$
A basis for the derivative is  $\mathscr B'= \{ax^{a-1}, a\in [0,n]\}$ with representative matrix $M\in M_{\mathbb R} (n,n)$ s.t. 
 $$[M]_{j,j+1}=j$$for $j\in[1,n]$. All other elements are zero. 
 Is it possible to find a closed form notation for the inverse $M^{-1}$? This would be equivalent to the integral operator under this vector space (minus a constant $c$). 
 I am mainly referring to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rqv3cXt8ZNU&t=925s) video by Michael Penn for inspiration. Keep in mind I've only taken Calc 1/2 and Introduction to Linear Algebra so far.

Comment: Don't we already have a closed form for integration of polynomials? You just turn $x^k$ into $x^{k+1}/(k+1)$.

Comment: I constructed the derivative matrix starting from a polynomial ring, and indeed I could go backwards and construct the antiderivative matrix. These two matrices multiplied would indeed yield the n-dimensional identity matrix. But why is it the case that I cannot directly calculate the inverse of M (as specified above)? As it has a zero determinant, I cannot just apply the usual formula for the construction of an inverse. (adj(M)/det(M)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot take the inverse because this matrix is not invertible, but the **pseudo-inverse** exist (I have checked it with Matlab function "pinv") :

$$\pmatrix{0&0&0&\cdot &0&0\\
1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&\tfrac12&0&\cdots&0&0\\
0&0&\tfrac13&\cdots&0&0\\
&&\cdots&&\\
0&0&0&\cdots & \frac{1}{n-1}&0}$$

Comment: For infinite matrices, see [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheDerivativeAndTheIntegralAsInfiniteMatrices/).

Comment: isn't the link explicitly for polynomials (so finite matrices)?

Comment: @lcv : You are right,  $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$  in one case, $\mathbb{R}[X]$ in the other. I just wanted to mention this kind of natural generalization.

Comment: I see, absolutely.